# How to copy max value of a cell data from one tab to another tab automatically by using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 12 months of data in Excel tab. I need to automatically copy the max month data into another tab by using formulas. By using vb script which is working. But I wanted to try with formulas.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `MAX` function to the sheet you need.
Example:
Function added in Sheet2 A1 Cell:

```
=MAX(Sheet1!1:1048576)
```

Comment: Will that work if I have more than 1 row also ?? Didn't understand how it is going to work out?? Can you please explain.

Comment: @Dileep Yes, the =MAX() function uses a range and will find the maximum value in the range

Comment: Ok. I need to include the column headers as well ?? Will that be possible.

Comment: @Dileep you don't need to specify column headers (You can do it but MAX function will omit them). `MAX` function find the highest numeric value in the range. In my example, find the MAX value in the entire Worksheet. In excel use the `Fx` Button in your formula bar and look for MAX function, this way you will have an assistant to provide you detailed help.